# Эталонный пример gevent TCP-сервера с форком процесса и демонизацией

Tags: python, сокет, асинхронность

Возьмем классический сценарий: сервер демонизируется, создает сокет, начинает его слушать, форкается для порождения воркеров, мастер процесс закрывает свою копию сокета, общается посредством сигналов с дочерними процессами, воркеры обслуживают свои копии сокета и ждут команд (сигналов) от мастера.

Я не нашел на эту тему официального примера от gevent. У gevent вообще много проблем с документацией. На Гитхабе есть проекты, в разной степени реализующие данный сценарий, но соответствующий код сильно отличается и у них много issues касательно именно применения gevent в данном сценарии. Из того, что я нашел на эту тему :

1. [tproxy](https://github.com/benoitc/tproxy) - целостный проект, по-своему реализующий данный сценарий, достаточно объемный.
2. [geventserver](https://github.com/surfly/geventserver) - еще одна полностью оригинальная законченная реализация сервера.
3. Чей-то [пример](https://gist.github.com/damoxc/919394/eed96390872bd0b79b22c434b96e2083a8c0fd7e) иллюстрирует форк и работу gevent.server.StreamServer, который выглядит удобно, но почему-то не используется нигде в других примерах, вместо этого остальные используют прямые операции на сокете (почему?)
   Вообще, странная реализация, но очень компактная. Можно ли доверять автору? Можно ли это брать за основу в продакшн коде?
4. [geventdaemon](https://github.com/gwik/geventdaemon) - отдельная библиотека для демонизации gevent, предоставляет класс, наследуемый от DaemonContext, который не используется нигде в других примерах (почему?).
5. И [еще один](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/70313/gevent.fork) полностью оригинальный пример, частично затрагивающий данную тему.

Все эти проекты имеют мало общего между собой, каждый подходит к проблеме совершенно по-своему, код у многих достаточно объемный, логика, относящаяся непосредственно к данному сценарию, размазана по коду и перемешана с прикладной логикой. В общем, весь этот код трудно использовать в качестве примера.

Так как же при использовании gevent **правильно** демонизировать и форкать сервер и взаимодействовать мастер-процессу с воркерами?

Comment: "эталонность" зависит от способа развёртывания. Во многих случаях *правильное* решение НЕ демонизирует сервис самостоятельно, оставляя это на ответственности процесса, организующего запуск/остановку сервиса. Для сравнения: [требования для новых демонов](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/daemon.html#New-Style%20Daemons) и [требования для старых демонов](http://goo.gl/4olrRs) -- последнее на Питоне, реализуется либо самостоятельно (как `twistd` делает) или с помощью пакета [python-daemon](https://goo.gl/DELYUl) ([полезно на список из PEP 3143 посмотреть](https://goo.gl/XERSzq))

Comment: @jfs: Что дает соответствие требованиям для новых демонов? Systemd прекрасно запускает старые демоны, а новые демоны становятся непереносимыми, я не прав?

Comment: `systemd` просто пример. Другие примеры: supervisord, circus, runit. Суть в том что существуют проблемы (неустранимые) у сервисов, которые сами себя демонизируют и иногда лучше этого не делать в зависимости от того как вы сервисы развёртываете.